# Mozilla Firefox Drop Down not working

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser

I am currently trying to debug an issue I have a drop down in a table
[image: drop down]

However in chrome and ie these drop downs work,
but in firefox it does not?.

I also have other drop downs on this page and they work fine in firefox

code

[image: code]

cheers

:)

Comment: please you can post your code or fiddle?

Comment: added a image of the code @Jainam

Comment: the css file for this is huge to be honest

Comment: You need to add your full code, where we are able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Probably something cover your dropdown.